# Unable to parse command line long options

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, getopt-long

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -sw
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $remote = 0;
my $test = 0;
GetOptions ('remote' => \$remote, 'test' => \$test);
print "$remote:$test\n";
```

perl test.pl --remote --test

The above prints "0:0". I am new to Perl so I have been unable to determine why this isn't working.

I also ran the "Simple Options" section from http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Simple-options and that didn't produce anything either.

Comment: @raina77ow - I did have them, just didn't include in this post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the `-s` command line option you include on your she-bang line is biting you. According to the [perlrun documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html), the `-s` command line option:

> enables rudimentary switch parsing for switches on the command line after the program name but before any filename arguments (or before an argument of --).

If you remove that option, things should work as you expect. I would also recommend removing the `-w` since you are already using the `use warnings` directive (the `use warnings` directive is much more fully featured, essentially replacing the `-w` option).

So, long story short, make your first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using that for short commands earlier but wanted to replace those (since I was using full words anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if running the script on Windows via cmd you must specify `perl` before the script name otherwise GetOptions doesn't work.

When I tried simply calling my script.pl on the command line without first putting `perl` the script ran but all the options weren't parsed.